# How to create a short cut for the app to my desktop, instead of using terminal?

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, scripting, osx

How do I access the game file in program files (x86) in script editor to create the shortcut?

I enter this cmd in the terminal:

```
cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/ubisoft/prince\ of\ persia/prince\ of\ persia.exe/
```

But in script editor this doesn't work, for some reason typing the (x86) doesn't allow it to, and the spaces are wrong too.

So how to write the command I wrote in script editor?

Comment: what system are you doing this on ?

Comment: Mac OSX is the system i'm running.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to make a shortcut to run the Game with Wine, here's how you do it.

Create a launcher shell script, and then make a .desktop format entry for it, and place it in *"~/.local/share/applications"*. This will add it to the system menu and can be opened like any other program.

Create a file called *princeofpersia.sh* in *~/.wine*.
Place the following contents, exactly as here, in it:

```
cd "~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/ubisoft/prince of persia/"
wine "$PWD/prince of persia.exe"
```

Now, navigate to *~./local/share/applications*
Place a file called *princeofpersia.desktop* there.
Put the following contents, exactly as here, inside it.

```
[DesktopEntry]
Type=Application
Name=Prince of Persia
Exec=bash ~/.wine/princeofpersia.sh
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Game;ArcadeGame;
Keywords=game;arcade;platform;
```

Log out and back in, it should now be present under the
"Games" section next to all the native Linux applications.

If it dosen't show up the first time, so this.
You may need to set permissions with these commands.

```
chmod a+x ~./local/share/applications/princeofpersia.desktop
chmod a+x ~./wine/princeofpersia.sh
```

Then,logout and login again, and it should be there.
If that still dosen't work, try running *~/.wine/princeofpersia.sh*

from a command terminal, and tell me any errors it gives you.

Comment: where is it that i write the following code
cd "~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/ubisoft/prince of persia/"
wine "$PWD/prince of persia.exe"
? btw i have a mac osx
@TheNH813

Comment: The ./local/share/applications folder dosen't exist on OSX for creating shortcuts. You should have specified you were using a Mac in the original question. Ignore all the other instructions I gave you except for the first one. Which is creating princeofpersia.sh. Put the file anywhere you want, as long as the first two lines containing the cd and wine commands match.